# PrimeFaces Bar Chart Formatting

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, bar-chart, sjplot

I'm trying to do 2 things on my Bar Chart:

1. Change the format of the number of yaxis to ###,###(12000) instead of ######(12000);
2. Changing the mouse `tooltip` to show just the y axis value. 14554 in instead of 1,14554

I've tried using custom extender, but I couldn't find out the JPlot code to it.

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want with your primefaces bar chart, add following to your custom `jqPlot` extender:

1. To format `Y axes` numbers as `###,###` (digit grouping)

   `this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "%'d";`

   (`jqPlot` uses single quote (') to format number with digit grouping)
2. To force `tooltip` to show only `yaxis` values

   `this.cfg.highlighter={show: true,tooltipAxes: 'y',useAxesFormatters: false,tooltipFormatString: "%'d"};`